# Unlock lock in a db table

Tags: oracle, locking

I want to unlock the locks obtained on a table. I tried killing the session but i dont have the dba privilege. Is there any way to do it? Executing COMMIT or ROLLBACK afterward didn't help, because since I started Oracle SQL Developer I got a new session ID. After a while Oracle removed the inactive sessions and locks, but I would like to have a way to remove the locks as a non-admin user

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for non-dba sessions to kill other sessions, or interfere with their locks in any way. Think about it. That would be a security disaster.

You need to issue your commit or rollback in the same session that launched the query. If you lose the session, you must ask your DBA to kill it for you.